# How to create a global hotkey?

Tags: c#

I want to create a hotkey, so when you press, it should write some bytes to a memory adress in the process I attached.
Till now, I have this code, but it seems it works only if I have the focus on main application, otherwise it won't work.
I want to make it work, so it'll do what I want, even if I don't have the focus on main application.

```
       private void MainPage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
                {
                 //my code here
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a class for that:

```
/// <summary>
/// Hook del teclado.
/// </summary>
public class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identificador del hook de teclado.
    /// </summary>
    private static IntPtr _hookId;

    /// <summary>
    /// Número de hooks asociados.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly List<KeyboardHook> HooksObjects = new List<KeyboardHook>();

    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        OnCreateKeyboardHook(this);
    }

    public KeyboardHook(Form form)
    {
        OnCreateKeyboardHook(this);

        form.Closed += (sender, e) => this.Dispose();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ocurre al pulsar una tecla.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<KeyEventArgs> KeyDown;

    /// <summary>
    /// Ocurre al soltar una tecla.
    ///  </summary>
    public event EventHandler<KeyEventArgs> KeyUp;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        HooksObjects.Remove(this);

        if (HooksObjects.Count == 0)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookId);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invocado al crear un objeto <see cref="KeyboardHook"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">Objeto <see cref="KeyboardHook"/>.</param>
    private static void OnCreateKeyboardHook(KeyboardHook obj)
    {
        if (HooksObjects.Count == 0)
        {
            _hookId = SetHook(KeyboardProc);
        }

        HooksObjects.Add(obj);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Establece el hook de teclado.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="proc">Función a invocar cuando se pulsa una tecla.</param>
    /// <returns>El identificador del hook.</returns>
    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (var curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (var curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            var modHandle = GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName);
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, modHandle, 0);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mantenemos una referencia para evitar una excepción.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly LowLevelKeyboardProc KeyboardProc = HookCallback;

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    #region Native

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;

    private const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            var keyDown = wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYDOWN;
            if (keyDown || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP || wParam == (IntPtr)WM_SYSKEYUP)
            {
                var kbd = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
                
                var vkCode = kbd.vkCode;
                var key = (Keys) vkCode;

                if (keyDown)
                {
                    if ((Keys) vkCode != Keys.Alt && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) != 0)
                    {
                        key |= Keys.Alt;
                    }

                    if ((Keys) vkCode != Keys.Control && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
                    {
                        key |= Keys.Control;
                    }

                    if ((Keys) vkCode != Keys.Shift && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
                    {
                        key |= Keys.Shift;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var flags = kbd.flags;
                    if (flags == KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags.LLKHF_ALTDOWN)
                    {
                        key = key | Keys.Alt;
                    }
                    else if (flags == 0x00)
                    {
                        key = key | Keys.Control;
                    }
                }

                var e = new KeyEventArgs(key) { Handled = false };

                foreach (var hookObject in HooksObjects)
                {
                    if (keyDown)
                    {
                        hookObject.KeyDown?.Invoke(hookObject, e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hookObject.KeyUp?.Invoke(hookObject, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public uint vkCode;
        public uint scanCode;
        public KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags flags;
        public uint time;
        public UIntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KBDLLHOOKSTRUCTFlags : uint
    {
        LLKHF_EXTENDED = 0x01,
        LLKHF_INJECTED = 0x10,
        LLKHF_ALTDOWN = 0x20,
        LLKHF_UP = 0x80,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod,
        uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    #endregion
}
```

You can create a hook for the keyboard with any of the constructors. If you are working with a Form, use that constructor and, when form it's closed, the hook is disposed. It's so important dispose the hook because works with OS level.

With the keyboard hook you get all key press in any application, with or without focus.

Simply create the hook and set events KeyDown and/or KeyUp in the same form that you can do in a Form control.

Comment: All that code, and global performance penalty, when all you really wanted is [`RegisterHotKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey)? I swear, some day I'll publish a .NET-insinuated CO2-footprint report.

Comment: @IInspectable RegisterHotKey has some problems. For example, it's consume the key stroke. If you press F1 to see notepad help, with RegisterHotKey, notepad don't show the help because you consume the key press. May be that the question wants, or not, it isn't specified. Also, if other application register the same key and you try to do the same, the function fails. It also has problems when you have the application in the tray.

Comment: @IInspectable I gave a solution, based on a keyboard hook, and I don't see any problem with this. It's simple to use (new KeyboardHook(form) and add an event handler to KeyDown/KeyUp event). I used this class in other scenary, in which I need several key combinations to handle in background my application while interact with an emulator. You should not disregard a solution simply because you think you have a better one, even if it were better. Everyone contributes according to his knowledge. If no one give another solution, it may be the only alternative to solve Lepis problem.

Comment: *"I don't see any problem with this."* - The problem is this: Installing a low-level keyboard hook is a **highly** intrusive operation. The system now has to context-switch on every input. That's thousands of CPU instructions, just to let the system know: *"Not what I was listening for. Thanks for asking anyway"*. Not just does this add to every other hook installed, it also means that the memory page holding the hook procedure cannot reasonably be paged to disk. RAM wasted, for nothing.

Comment: The only reason you would ever want to install a low-level hook is if you wish to prevent the input from being passed on to the system. Incidentally, that's what you call a *"problem"* with `RegisterHotKey`. In essence, what you're proposing is to use a solution whose sole justification is one you are judiciously evading to take advantage of. If you need to *monitor* input (without intercepting it), [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) would be the way to go. This proposed answer is simply picking the worst of all worlds, with a nice facade.

Comment: "That's thousands of CPU instructions": Intel Core i7 2600K (2011) execute 117160 MIPS at 3.4 GHz. So thousands instructions... we are talking about 0.0000000085% of CPU wasted per second. I'm sure that you are not able to tell my if I install or not a keyboard hook due to speed or RAM consumption. If you have a deep knowledge about this topics, give solutions and expond the pros/const, but but don't despise those of others, even if they are worse. An assembler programmer could give an opinion similar to yours to 99% of questions because at high level, everything loses performance/resources.

Comment: I didn't know about RegisterHotKey or Raw Input. I haven't said that RegisterHotKey is not the best solution: I have indicated possible problems that it may have and I understand that it is good for Lepis. If they aren't problems for him, then he should opt for that solution. But if you don't explain things to him, he will hardly be able to choose judiciously. Having your knowledge, you should expose your solutions and let Lepis choose the one he understands that is best for his case instead of despising mine, which is the one I know and that is why I expose it.

Comment: *"we are talking about 0.0000000085% of CPU"* - Leaving aside, that you're using that CPU time for *nothing* in return, it's not so much about the time taken as it is about the fact, that the thread needs to wake. That not only consumes time, but also energy. Battery for mobile devices, including laptops. *"An assembler programmer could give an opinion"* - This is not about micro-optimizations. It's about understanding the system. I would submit an answer if the question wasn't systems programming hostile by confining it to .NET/C#.

Comment: How much time do you spend to wake up a thread? less than 50 micro seconds? How many times user press a key per second? less than 1 on average? How many seconds of battery are you going to lose with a keyboard hook installed? It's true, you must be careful with hooks (avoid errors, call to next hook, be fast processing the hook procedure) but It's an option. It's like exception handling. It has  a big penalty in performance (when exception is thrown) but it's used. You must use it carefully, only for real exceptions. It's an option and widely used.

Comment: If you (an expert) are able to detect differences when some application has o not the hook installed, I will agree with you and advise against the use of the hook. You say that you don't want give solutions but you are fine with disregarding the contribution I make and you are unwilling to make because this question is (hostile for you) about .NET.